# Как сделать ограниченно количество записей в бд?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite3

Как сделать ограничение на количество одинаковых записей в бд?
Например, мне нужно чтобы один пользователь мог оставить только 5 записей. Соответственно к каждой записи прикрепляется ячейка с id пользователя., т.е. в столбце должно быть не более 5 одинаковых записей id пользователя.
бд если что sqlite3
Описал проблему как смог) Надеюсь вы поймете...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65766981/sqlite-creating-a-trigger-to-limit-the-maximum-entries-with-a-given-identifier

Comment: Доп. таблица, которая для каждого пользователя хранит количество записей с constraint на поле количества. Триггеры на основную таблицу, которые при вставке/удалении в основную таблицу обновляют таблицу с количествами.